# Is it allowed to quote a question of a other site on the Stack Exchange network?

Tags: discussion

Recently, I found a question on Arqade that was similar to a question on the other site on the network. From my experience, duplicates between the whole Stack Exchange network are not possible. **Is it allowed to quote the answer to the similar question and post it as a answer to the question on Arqade, quoting it and linking to the original question?**

Comment: "From my experience, duplicates between the whole Stack Exchange network are not possible." This is incorrect. Two sites can support the same question, if that question is defined as in-scope for both sites. For example, both the films site and the sci-fi site could support questions on Star Wars.

Comment: @StrixVaria If both the films site and sci-fi site have a very similar question, is it considered a duplicate then or not?

Comment: We don't mark cross-site things as duplicates.

Comment: It is not a duplicate. Different sites function as, effectively, completely separate entities who set their own rules without respect to the rules of other sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally do not see any problem with this, as you are giving attribution to the person who originally wrote the answer on the other site. If it is a long answer however, I would only quote the most relevant parts and if possible add a little detail of your own. Quoting from another post on a different SE site is not really any different that quoting from another source.

Comment: SE content is licensed under CC-BY-SA, which stipulates that you can use the content so long as you a) Provide attribution (quote them, link back to original), and b) Provide the same rights you have to quote/copy/share to people who then wish to use your version. As Arqade is *also* under CC-BY-SA, this is automatically applied.

Comment: @Robotnik thanks for that info.